# boost::io_service How to guarantee handler execution sequence

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I have a thread pool with `boost::io_service` on top. I use it for different CPU-bound tasks in whole application. For some tasks, I have to guarantee that tasks will be executed in specified order (decoding video stream). Using `io_service::strand` guaranties that tasks will not be executed currently, but it has no guarantee about the order of execution. In other words, task #5 may be executed before task #4. Is there any method to solve that problem, other than scheduling next task after executing of current.

Comment: Since you have a thread pool, define "after". 5 must start after 4 starts? After 4 ends? Must end after 4 ends? If by "after" you mean 5 must start after 4 ends, then why do you not want to schedule it at the end of 4?

Comment: task #5 should be executed after task #4 ends.

Comment: I do
io_service.post(task#4);
io_service.post(task#5);

and want it executed in the posted order, as if there only one working thread.

Comment: > then why do you not want to schedule it at the end of 4?
The reason is - I don't want to create queue of tasks. Tasks are scheduled by event cumming from external system.

Comment: why not a task queue? And threading is pointless if you have to have an order.

Comment: re-read the [strand documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service__strand.order_of_handler_invocation). Ordering can be guaranteed.

Comment: When decoding a video stream, is there intermediate output in real time?  Or, is it more like a block of data that goes through a somewhat lengthy decoding process and the result is that perhaps a display method or save method is called with a pointer to the decoded block of data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strand` provides both the guarantee of not executing completion handlers concurrently and defines the order of handler invocation.  In short, completion handlers posted into a `strand` are executed in the same order in which they are posted.

Therefore:

```
strand_.post(&task1);
strand_.post(&task2);
strand_.post(&task3);
```

Guarantees order of handler invocation is `task1` -> `task2` -> `task3`.  However, wrapped completion handlers for asynchronous operations are not guaranteed, as the order in which asynchronous operations are performed is unspecified.  For example, the following does not provide the same guarantee:

```
async_read(socket1, ..., strand_.wrap(&task1));
async_read(socket2, ..., strand_.wrap(&task2));
async_read(socket3, ..., strand_.wrap(&task3));
```

If completion handlers must be invoked in a specified order for asynchronous operations, then either:

- Queue completion handlers and manage the order manually.
- Serialize all asynchronous operations.  For example, `async_op_1`'s completion handler `task1` initiates `async_op_2` with a completion handler of `task2`.

---

Here is the relevant excerpt from `io_service::strand`'s [order of handler invocation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service__strand.order_of_handler_invocation) documentation:

> Given:
>
> - a strand object `s`
> - an object `a` meeting completion handler requirements
> - an object `a1` which is an arbitrary copy of a made by the implementation
> - an object `b` meeting completion handler requirements
> - an object `b1` which is an arbitrary copy of b made by the implementation
>
> if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - `s.post(a)` happens-before `s.post(b)`
> - ...
>
> then `asio_handler_invoke(a1, &a1)` happens-before
>   `asio_handler_invoke(b1, &b1)`.