# Confused about boost::asio::yield order of execution in same strand

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I am trying to write a Client with asio that does the following:

1. Connects to a server.
2. Tries to read back some data *after* it is connected to the server.

The problem I am finding is that operations do not seem to be executed in sequence, as I would expect. Here it is the code:

```
std::future<NetMessage> Cliente::asyncConnectTo(std::string const & hostname,
                                          int port,
                                          std::string const & name) {
    using namespace std::literals;
    boost::asio::spawn
        (strand_,
         [this, name, port, hostname](boost::asio::yield_context yield) mutable {
            i_->playerLog->trace() << name << " connecting to " << hostname << ':'
                                   << port;
            Guinyote::Utils::connectWith
                (*this, std::move(hostname), port,
                 std::move(name), yield);

            i_->playerLog->info() << "Connected to server.";
        });
    runthread_ = std::thread([&] {
            try {
                i_->playerLog->info() << "Starting...";
                this->service_.run();
            }
            catch (std::exception & e) {
                std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
        });
    return this->asyncReceiveMessage(); //This function spawns another coroutine through the same strand_ object.
}
```

The function `this->asyncReceiveMessage()` is expected to receive a message that the server sends back after connecting:

```
std::future<NetMessage> Cliente::asyncReceiveMessage() {
    namespace ba = boost::asio;

    std::promise<NetMessage> prom;
    std::future<NetMessage> message = prom.get_future();
    ba::spawn
        (strand_,
         [this, p = std::move(prom)](boost::asio::yield_context yield) mutable {
            i_->playerLog->trace("waiting to read message from server socket...");
            boost::system::error_code ec{};
            boost::int64_t messageSize{};
            ba::async_read(
                socket_,
                ba::buffer(&messageSize, sizeof(boost::int64_t)),
                yield);

            i_->playerLog->trace() << "Client: Received message of "
                                   << messageSize << " bytes. Reading message...";

            std::vector<char> serverMessageData(messageSize);
            ba::async_read
                (socket_,
                 ba::buffer(serverMessageData),
                 yield);

            using namespace boost::iostreams;
            basic_array_source<char> input_source(&serverMessageData[0], serverMessageData.size());
            stream<basic_array_source<char>> stream(input_source);
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(stream);
            Utils::MensajeRed msg;

            archive >> msg;
            i_->playerLog->trace() << "NetMessage correctly read.";
            p.set_value(std::move(msg));

        });
    return message;
}
```

In my log file I am getting the following on client side:

```
[clientLog] [info] Client: Starting...
[clientLog] [trace] User1234 connecting to localhost:10004
[clientLog] [trace] waiting to read message from server socket...
```

But I would expect that the third line of that log would come after `[clientLog] [info] Connected to server.` So my expectation is the following:

```
[clientLog] [info] Client: Starting...
[clientLog] [trace] User1234 connecting to localhost:10004
[clientLog] [info] Connected to server.
[clientLog] [trace] waiting to read message from server socket...
```

Namely, "Connected to server" should always happen *before* "waiting to read message from server socket...".

Does anyone know what is going on? I thought `strand_` would guarantee order of execution, but it seems I may have misunderstood something. What is the correct solution to get the effect I want?

Comment: I see this is the same but I do not see a proper solution. It just says something like "handle by hand" actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946555/boostio-service-how-to-guarantee-handler-execution-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that the tasks are going to be started in order, but subsequent `boost::asio::spawn` spawn invocations in chain does not mean the first task will finish before the second.

It will just happen that *the first task is started before the second task*, nothing else.

In order to keep the order, I just created a coroutine that is invoked inside the spawn in `asyncConnectTo`, instead of spawning two different coroutines. This way I make sure the first coroutine finishes before the second:

```
NetMessage Cliente::asyncReceiveMessageCoro(boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
    namespace ba = boost::asio;
    i_->playerLog->trace("waiting to read message from server socket...");
    boost::system::error_code ec{};
    boost::int64_t messageSize{};
    ba::async_read(
      socket_,
      ba::buffer(&messageSize, sizeof(boost::int64_t)),
      yield);

    i_->playerLog->trace() << "Client: Received message of "
                                   << messageSize << " bytes. Reading message...";

    std::vector<char> serverMessageData(messageSize);
    ba::async_read
       (socket_,
        ba::buffer(serverMessageData),
        yield);

    using namespace boost::iostreams;
    basic_array_source<char> input_source(&serverMessageData[0], serverMessageData.size());
    stream<basic_array_source<char>> stream(input_source);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(stream);
    Utils::MensajeRed msg;

    archive >> msg;
    i_->playerLog->trace() << "NetMessage correctly read.";
    return msg;
}
```

This coroutine can be chained at the end:

```
std::future<NetMessage> Cliente::asyncConnectTo(std::string const & hostname,
                                          int port,
                                          std::string const & name) {
    using namespace std::literals;

    std::promise<NetMessage> msgProm;
    auto msg = msgProm.get_future();
    boost::asio::spawn
        (strand_,
         [this, name, port, hostname, p = std::move(msgProm)](boost::asio::yield_context yield) mutable {
            i_->playerLog->trace() << name << " connecting to " << hostname << ':'
                                   << port;
            Guinyote::Utils::connectWith
                (*this, std::move(hostname), port,
                 std::move(name), yield);

            i_->playerLog->info() << "Connected to server.";
            p.set_value(this->asyncReceiveCoro(yield));
        });
    runthread_ = std::thread([&] {
            try {
                i_->playerLog->info() << "Starting...";
                this->service_.run();
            }
            catch (std::exception & e) {
                std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
        });
    return msg;
}
```

My old `asyncReceiveMessage` just becomes a combination of `spawn` + calling the `asyncReceiveMessageCoro`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your findings